# Resolve Generic Properties in Expression to use in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, expression

We are currently rewriting a lot of duplicate code to manage our Database Queries (with EF) in a very generic fashion. Right now, we are facing some problems with resolving the correct Property Value to use in Expressions.

```
private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildGenericSearchExpression()
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = x => false;
    
    var searchFields = GenericTableOptions.SearchColumns;
    var propertyInfos = GetSearchColumnsAsProperties(typeof(TEntity), searchFields).ToList();

    if (propertyInfos.Count ==  0)
    {
        return expression;
    }
    
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        var value = propertyInfo.Name;

        expression = x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null).ToString().Contains("Hans");
    }

    return expression;
}

private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetSearchColumnsAsProperties(Type targetType,  IEnumerable<string> properties)
{
    IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    
    if (targetType == null)
    {
        throw new GenericTableException($"Type has no value set");
    }
    
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var propertyInfo = targetType?.GetProperty(property);
        
        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new GenericTableException($"Property {property} is not available on Type {targetType}");
        }
        
        propertyInfos.Add(propertyInfo);
    }
    
    return propertyInfos;
}
```

For a quick Test, I have created a basic User class.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

FirstName is set as the Search Column and "Hans" is used as the search term.

The internal test list uses two users with different FirstNames, but it always returns both of them.

```
public Task<IList<User>> FindPaginatedAsync(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate, int page, int size)
{
    IList<User> users = new List<User> { new User { FirstName = "Hans" }, new User { FirstName = "Franz" }};

    IList<User> result = users.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
    
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

The created Expression is passed as the predicate, page and size aren't used yet. Any Ideas on that how to get me out of that rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just if anyone falls into the same trap.

`AsQueryable` returns an `IEnumerable` which does not execute the Query immediately. When you eventually convert it to a List the query gets executed and works as expected.

In our case, this will do the trick.

`var result = users.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();`

In the end we will keep working with the `IEnumerable` and convert it as late as possible.